# can i define sharedPreferences once and call it when i need data to display into flutter app?

Tags: flutter

i tried to declare the instance like this but it doesn't work

```
     void main() async{
     SharedPreferences appData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     runApp(const MyApp());
```

I would like to define the instance only once and call the global variable when i need

Comment: You can call it in MyApp class and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare it out the main method like this

```
late SharedPreferences appData;
```

and in the main assign it the instance like this

```
 void main() async{

 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 appData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 runApp(const MyApp());
 }
```

then you can use it any where you want

Comment: I tried with your solution with this result...    https://snipboard.io/HhmLjp.jpg

Comment: add this line at the start of the main widget WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();